# This is Dropdown can you please tell me how to select 2nd or 3rd option from the dropdown in selenium webdriver. Mr is default selected

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am not able to select from dropdown value. can you please help me out.

```
<div id="sbHolder_43830942" class="sbHolder" tabindex="1">
   <a id="sbToggle_43830942" class="sbToggle" href="#"/>
   <a id="sbSelector_43830942" class="sbSelector" href="#">Mr.</a>
   <ul id="sbOptions_43830942" class="sbOptions" style="top: 24px; max-height: 100px; display: none;">
      <li><a class="" href="#Mr" rel="Mr">Mr.</a> </li>`
      <li><a class="" href="#Ms" rel="Ms">Ms.</a></li> 
      <li><a class="" href="#Mrs" rel="Mrs">Mrs.</a></li>
      <li><a class="" href="#Mx" rel="Mx">Mx.</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: <div id="sbHolder_43830942" class="sbHolder" tabindex="1">
<a id="sbToggle_43830942" class="sbToggle" href="#"/>
<a id="sbSelector_43830942" class="sbSelector sbFocus" href="#">Mr.</a>
<ul id="sbOptions_43830942" class="sbOptions" style="top: 24px; max-height: 283px; display: none;">
<li>
<a class="" href="#Mr" rel="Mr">Mr.</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="" href="#Ms" rel="Ms">Ms.</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="" href="#Mrs" rel="Mrs">Mrs.</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="" href="#Mx" rel="Mx">Mx.</a>
</li>
</ul>

Comment: above is my code.. here i don't have select option.. all are kept in <a> tag

Comment: Tried to fix code formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//clicks on the drop down box

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='sbSelector']")).click();

//select options from drop down box based on rel attribute

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='sbOptions']/li/a[@rel='Ms']")).click();
```

Change the rel attribute to Mrs,Mx to select the respective option as per your requirement

I checked with the above code it worked fine

Hope this helps you...Kindly get back if you have any queries

Comment: above is my code.. Here I don't have select option.. All are kept in <a> tag

Comment: https://www.online.citibank.co.in/products-services/loans/home-loan-callback.htm?eOfferCode=CBOLMNU - in this screen Name dropdown I am facing issue. can any one please help me out

Comment: @OleManjunath I have edited my above response and added the code Kindly refer it...Hope it helps you

Comment: const DEFAULT_MAX_INSTANCES = 4
exports.config = {
specs: [
    // 'app/e2e/content/ApplicationDetails.feature'
    'test/e2e/content/SSOPSIT_1444_SanitySingleCustomer.feature'
  ],
  // Patterns to exclude.
  exclude: [
    // './.github',
    // './node_modules',
    // './test'
  ],
maxInstances: parseInt(process.env.MAX_INSTANCES) || DEFAULT_MAX_INSTANCES,

Comment: capabilities: [{
    // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
    // grid with only 5 firefox instance available you can make sure that not more than
    // 5 instance gets started at a time.
    maxInstances: 1,
    //
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }],

sync: true,
  //
  // Level of logging verbosity: silent | verbose | command | data | result | error
  logLevel: 'verbose',
  //
  // Enables colors for log output.
  coloredLogs: true,
  //
  // Saves a screenshot to a given path if a command fails.

Comment: // Saves a screenshot to a given path if a command fails.
  screenshotPath: 'test/e2e/errorShots/',
waitforTimeout: 1000000,
connectionRetryTimeout: 900000,
connectionRetryCount: 3,
services: ['selenium-standalone'],
framework: 'cucumber',
  //
  // Test reporter for stdout.
  // The only one supported by default is 'dot'
  // see also:allure generate [allure_output_dir] && allure open
  //  DocReporter
  reporters: ['spec', 'junit', 'allure'],

Comment: reporterOptions: {
    captureStandardOutput: false,
    flowId: true,
    message: '[title]',
    allure: {
      outputDir: 'reports/e2e/allure-results'
    },
    junit: {
      outputDir: 'reports/e2e/.junit'
    }
    // outputDir: 'reports/e2e'
  },

cucumberOpts: {
    require: [
      'test/e2e/step_definitions/core-steps/given.js',
      'test/e2e/step_definitions/core-steps/then.js',
      'test/e2e/step_definitions/core-steps/when.js',
      'test/e2e/step_definitions/custom-steps/'
    ],

Comment: backtrace: false,   // <boolean> show full backtrace for errors
    compiler: ['js:babel-register'],       // <string[]> ("extension:module") require files with the given EXTENSION after requiring MODULE (repeatable)
    dryRun: false,      // <boolean> invoke formatters without executing steps
    failFast: false,    // <boolean> abort the run on first failure
    format: ['pretty'], // <string[]> (type[:path]) specify the output format, optionally supply PATH to redirect formatter output (repeatable)

Comment: colors: true,       // <boolean> disable colors in formatter output
    snippets: true,     // <boolean> hide step definition snippets for pending steps
    source: true,       // <boolean> hide source uris
    profile: [],        // <string[]> (name) specify the profile to use
    strict: false,      // <boolean> fail if there are any undefined or pending steps
    // tags: require('./../../e2e/tagProcessor'),           // <string[]> (expression) only execute the features or scenarios with tags matching the expression

Comment: timeout: 200000,     // <number> timeout for step definitions
    ignoreUndefinedDefinitions: false // <boolean> Enable this config to treat undefined definitions as warnings.
  },

// =====
  // Hooks

Comment: before: function () {
    require('babel-register')
    var chai = require('chai')
    global.winston = require('winston')
    winston.level = 'debug'
    global.expect = chai.expect
    global.assert = chai.assert
    global.should = chai.should()
    global.fieldIdsOfPages = {}
    let jsonfile = require('jsonfile')
    let file = './test/e2e/test_support/testdata/testdata.json'
    jsonfile.readFile(file, function (err, obj) {
      global.referenceData = obj
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    })

Comment: // maximize browser window
    browser.windowHandleSize({width: 1366, height: 768})
    // browser.windowHandleMaximize()

    // bring browser window to foreground so we can see it
    browser.saveScreenshot()
  },

onPrepare: function onPrepare (exitCode) {
    global.winston = require('winston')
    winston.debug('onComplete')
    var node_cmd = require('node-cmd')
    node_cmd.get('rm -r reports/e2e/allure-results', function (err, data, stderr) {
      winston.debug(err)
      winston.debug(data)
      winston.debug(stderr)
    })

Comment: var cmd = 'rm -r reports/e2e/allure-report'
    node_cmd.get(cmd, function (err, data, stderr) {
      winston.debug(err)
      winston.debug(data)
      winston.debug(stderr)
    })
  },
  onComplete: function onComplete (exitCode) {
    global.winston = require('winston')
    winston.debug('onComplete')
    var node_cmd = require('node-cmd')
    node_cmd.get('ls -al reports/e2e/allure-results', function (err, data, stderr) {

Comment: // NOTE put allure on path in bash profile
    var cmd = 'cd  reports/e2e/ && allure generate -c'
    node_cmd.get(cmd, function (err, data, stderr) {
      winston.debug(err)
      winston.debug(data)
      winston.debug(stderr)
    })
  }
}

Comment: Can you please help me out for above query

Comment: var config = require('./wdio.conf.js').config config.baseUrl = 'https://ssop-fuchsia.csp.service.dev' exports.config = config